# Can I get access to Ubuntu apps on Ubuntu touch if I allow read write access?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, application-development, android, skype

Okay so I'm an impatient bastard who realises he should have waited but purchased the BQ HD5 Ubuntu mobile phone back in June whilst being fully aware it didn't have that many apps available as was just for developers or impatient bastards like me, but I went ahead anyway as I was excited to try it out.

Unfortunately I really need a voIP application like Skype due to the work I do (I've actually paid about £150 for a full years worth of unlimited calls to European mobiles and landlines for Skype).

I'm aware we have that Skype (unofficial) app in the app store which allows you to chat, but that isn't sufficient for what I need.

So as I see it I have two options, I either buy a cheapish new handset like a MS or Android and stick my Ubuntu phone away in my bedroom and get it out in six months time and run some updates and see what is available or I hack at it now on the off chance there is a way to mitigate against my voIP issue.

What got me thinking was as I'm also running Ubuntu as my DE on my laptop one of the things I'm curious about is considering Canonical are developing Unity 8 with convergence and there are existing desktop applications for Ubuntu desktop  that are not available for the mobile such as Spotify and Skype what would happen if I was to enable read write access on my Ubuntu mobile phone and then within the terminal on my touch device use the sudo apt-get instructions to install Skype as I would do on my desktop?

As both phone and laptop are running 15.10 it should then install Skype on my mobile as it would on my desktop or is the converged code still some way off and I'd be likely to brake my device?

Thanks in advance,